# cURL Port and URL

Tags: php, curl, bittorrent

I'm trying to help my friend test his anti-cheat program on his torrent tracker. The announce URL of his tracker is:

"http://www.exampletorrentsite.com:60000/3b74fb48a6247bc8er6s1b85ec734d22/announce"

From what I understand, torrent announces uses the GET method, and I'm guessing that the query string is appended after the "/announce" and separated by a "?" character? Can anyone confirm this?

Also, another problem is the port number. In that form, most clients will know to connect on port 60000, but will cURL parse it and know it should connect on port 60000, or should I change the announce URL to not have the port number, and just put that in as the PORT setting?

Thanks for any and all clarifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure about the ports parsing, but I'm sure that you can take the safe route and set it manually using the curl_setopt command. As for the "?", yes, that is used to separate the announce URL from the query string.